# Why does print(inst.__repr__()) succeed when print(inst) fails with unicode error?

Tags: python-2.7, unicode

The sample class is below, in python 2.7

```
class Test(object):
    def __repr__(self):
        return u"Because He Lives 因他活着"
    def f(self):
        print(self)
```

If I create an instance `foo` of this class, `print(foo)` gives a unicode error but `print(foo.__repr__())` or `print(foo.__str__())` do not. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This is because the `repr()` function itself will try to convert a Unicode return value from a custom `__repr__()` method into a `str` object, in order to ensure that `repr()` only ever returns `str` values.

Unfortunately I can't find the relevant quote from the documentation right now, or I would have linked it. But to be more precise, when `__repr__()` is called, Python expects it to return a `str` object, and any other type will raise an exception, except `unicode`. The only reason `unicode` works is because of Python 2's standard implicit coercion between `unicode` and `str` objects, which is transparent until it isn't, like in your case.

Comment: Thanks, that helped me figure out what exactly to search. If you could add the following to your answer I'd be happy to accept it (just for completion) as this works for me:-

 class Test(object):
    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"Because He Lives 因他活着"
    def __repr__(self):
        return unicode(self).encode('utf-8')
    def f(self):
        print(self)

Comment: Ah that didn't come out very well. Just renamed __repr__ to __unicode__ and made __repr__ do a ''return unicode(self).encode('utf-8')''

Comment: @NgOon-Ee: `__repr__` method is a rare case when `unicode-escape` encoding is appropriate: `return 'Test(%s)' % repr(unicode(self))`. If you want to see a human readable string, print Unicode directly: `print(u"{}".format(Test()))`

Comment: @NgOon-Ee: I don't really agree that that is the proper answer to the question, though. `__unicode__()` means something else than `__repr__()`, just as `__str__()` does, so it would not be a generally valid answer.

Answer (score 0):

`print(obj)` converts `obj` to a string. In your case `repr()` is called (because `__str__` method is not defined).

`repr()` must return `str` type. If you call `repr()` instead of `__repr__()` then the constraint is enforced by encoding automatically using `sys.getdefaultencoding()` character encoding that should be ASCII on Python 2:

```
>>> class Test(object):
...     def __repr__(self):
...         return u"\N{SNOWMAN}" # non-ascii, unicode type
... 
>>> Test().__repr__() # no error
u'\u2603'
>>> repr(Test()) # error, the restriction on the return type is enforced
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2603' in position 0:
                    ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: The first line in this answer can't be correct, as that would imply that print(foo) and print(foo.__repr__()) would both not work. The latter works.

Comment: @NgOon-Ee: **wrong**. The first line in the answer does not mention `__repr__` at all. See the code example in the answer: do you understand the difference between `obj.__repr__()` and `repr(obj)`?

Comment: You mention that print converts to string, but it doesn't always, which is why print(foo.__repr__()) worked in my case. Unless what you meant is that only objects get converted to string (RIP duck-typing)?

Comment: @NgOon-Ee yes, `print` always converts to string (bytes or unicode). There is no `print(foo.__repr__())` in my answer.